# ServiceControl in a deployment with a distributor

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor

We didn't have any problem with the ServiceControl until we have deployed our solution with a distributor. Now the service works perfectly well with the old data, but it doesn't receive new one.

Do we have to configure something apart of the master node section to get the ServiceControl working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At the end you need to set the audit and error queues to point to the same queue in the cluster (even the machine).

http://particular-docs-test.cloudapp.net/nservicebus/auditing-with-nservicebus